# Redirect a specific hostname to another hostname

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, domain-name

I'm trying to redirect from an old hostname to the new one. So far I've got

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.company.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://bar.company.com/$1 [R=301]
```

but when I go to `foo.company.com/dir/page.html` I don't get redirected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out some mysterious incident caused three servers to reboot, including the old `foo.company.com`, it reverted to its old IP, and was fighting for it with the new server.

Got my rules working and refined them to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.company.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://bar.company.com/$1 [R=301]
```